# Datetimepicker comparing two dates/times

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I've looked through several posts, and tried several options to no avail can I compare two dates that include time from datetimepicker.

This is the jquery datetimepicker located here: https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

I have two times in a form like so:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<label for="">Start Time</label>
<input id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Click to Select"></td>
<td colspan="2">
<label for="">End-Time</label>
<input id="datetimepicker2" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Click to Select">
</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to be able to compare the start time and end time so there is a total number of hours field.

I know how to get the values from the inputs etc just not how to compare the final two dates when they are in the format of each below:

```
var startTime = $('#datetimepicker').val(); //2015/06/25 02:18

var endTime = $('#datetimepicker2').val(); //2015/06/27 12:25

var timesCompared = startTime -> endTime; //Calculate how many hours,minutes between the two dates (-> is just for visuals).
```

Thanks for any help that is provided.

Comment: you may use js plugin moment.js for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```js
var start_actual_time  =  "01/17/2012 11:20";
var end_actual_time    =  "01/18/2012 12:25";

start_actual_time = new Date(start_actual_time);
end_actual_time = new Date(end_actual_time);

var diff = end_actual_time - start_actual_time;

var diffSeconds = diff/1000;
var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds/3600);
var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds%3600)/60;

var formatted = ((HH < 10)?("0" + HH):HH) + ":" + ((MM < 10)?("0" + MM):MM);
alert(formatted);
```

[See this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/diode/nuv7t/5/)